# Polygons in maps package edge overlapping when generating polygons for U.S. States

Tags: r, maps, spatial

I'm working on some niche modelling and I'm using the maps package to generate polygons for states my species is endemic to.

```
endemic <- maps::map(database = "state", regions = c("alabama","florida","georgia","kentucky","mississippi","north carolina","pennsylvania","south carolina","tennessee","virginia","west virginia"), 
                     plot = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

The names of the states match the ones given by unique(states$region)

These are the spatial polygons.

```
endemic_sp <- map2SpatialPolygons(endemic, IDs = endemic$names, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
sf_endemic <- st_as_sf(endemic_sp, coords = c("long","lat"), crs = 4326)
```

These are the spatial points.

```
occ_points <- st_as_sf(point_data, coords = c("long","lat"), crs = 4326)
```

It gets an error on this step:

```
endemic_polygon <-  st_filter(occ_points, sf_endemic)

Error in `stopifnot()`:
In argument: `lengths(.predicate(x, y, ...)) > 0`.
Caused by error in `wk_handle.wk_wkb()`:
! Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 0 has duplicate vertex with edge 394.
```

The edge is overlapping for some reason, how do I fix this?

I tried checking for a syntax error in the States' names, checking the long and lat fields, and if they were using the same crs. All were correct, but the error is still there.

Comment: Have you tried using `st_make_valid` to fix the geometries?

Comment: Try setting `sf_use_s2(FALSE)` before running your code. This is because by default `sf` package uses spherical geometry rather than planar geometry as the default when coordinates are ellipsoidal.

Comment: I tried sf_use_s2(FALSE)  out, and it returns this message: "although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersects assumes that they are planar", which probably means it is changing distance. Is this an issue? st_make_valid still has the same error message as before.

Comment: It's only an issue if distance is critical to your analysis. In which case, you probably should be using a PCS/CRS that preserves distance (or area) anyway. Judging by your use case, it does not appear it will be a major issue, but without more information regarding how you intend to use the polygons, I can only guess.